# How to read flutter saved shared preference in android

Tags: android, flutter, sharedpreferences

I am new in flutter and dart. I have saved some data in shared preferences using dart. Now I need to read this data in android class. The reason is i want to receive boot events in my app and needs to read some settings when my app receive booting notification. Below is sample code i am using to read values but it is returning default value for keys. There is data available if i use dart to read values. Currently my app is only runs on android platform and not required for iOS

```
SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("settings", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
String value=preferences.getString("timeoutValue",2);
```

Comment: I didn't get your question. Do you want to know how Shared Preference works in flutter?

Comment: Can you please provide more brief pieces of information about your question?

Comment: SharedPreferences created in dart and i need to read in android class e.g(MainActivity.java)